# String.format in java

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста!

```
String a = "lat/lng: (61.68691031622721,64.41254910081625)";
```

Как из этой строки получить `String b = "61.6869"` и `String c = "64.4125"`?

Делаю так но не получается

```
textView.setText(String.format("lat/lng: (" + "%1$.4f&%2$.4f" + ")",a).toString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String.format` нужен чтобы "склеить" строку из нескольких значений.

Вам же нужно, наоборот, разобрать строку на части (а уже потом склеить). Для этого обычно используют регулярные выражения.

В вашем случае это будет что-то вроде `\((\d+.\d+),(\d+.\d+)\)`.

Использовать можно так:

```
    String a = "lat/lng: (61.68691031622721,64.41254910081625)";
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\((\\d+.\\d+),(\\d+.\\d+)\\)");
    Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(a);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        String b = matcher.group(1);
        String c = matcher.group(2);

        textView.setText(String.format("lat/lng: (" + "%1$.4f&%2$.4f" + ")", Double.parseDouble(b), Double.parseDouble(c)));
    }
```